# rkhunter psswd and group file changes warning

Tags: rootkit, rkhunter

Today I did a scan of my machine with `rkhunter`:

```
sudo rkhunter --checkall
```

And these were the warnings that I got:

```
Checking for passwd file changes                         [ Warning ]
Checking for group file changes                          [ Warning ]
```

Is this anything to worry about? And if it is then how should I proceed?

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ask yourself:

- did I add a user?
- did I install software that might have added a user?

Best method to use is to list the /etc/passwd file on your screen with

```
more /etc/passwd
```

and to check for unexpected usernames.

These notices from rkhunter are more than likely caused by an out of date reference file. You might want to do a ...

```
sudo rkhunter --update
sudo rkhunter --propupd
```

after you install new software. The 1st creates a new database reference file and the 2nd marks that reference file as a starting point.

If a rootkit is found it is likely to throw more alarms than just a notice regarding `/etc/passwd`. That is just a file holding your "users" and it is not enough to start a rootkit.